# Unable to view all backlog items at one place while picking them for a sprint

Tags: azure-devops

I still didn't get it.
Where do complete backlog stays if we have to plan for new sprint and pick items from backlog. Like I can see stories/features but what about all bugs/issues, where they can be seen?

I don't want to search for all items in queries/work items. How can I bring all work items in backlog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're using the Agile template, which doesn't put everything on the product backlog by default. You can edit the backlog settings to put the bug workitem on the backlog. You can find this setting in the Backlog customization screen, as long as Bug is configured to show up as a requirement, it should show up on the product backlog:

[image]

Since issues follow a completely different workflow, they cannot be placed on the product backlog. I would guess that they're being used as something else than what they were meant for. But you'd have to help me with additional information. The Issue work item type is the scrum equivalent of an Impediment. Anything that is blocking the team from progressing effectively. These aren't part of the work that goes into the product and are not managed on the same list.

If you're using the Issue work item as a different kind of Bug/Defect then I recommend either creating a custom field on bug to signal the bug type or create a new work item type that is a copy of bug to start with, that way it starts out with all the fields required for it to show up on the backlog.

Comment: After checking the checkbox, it(bug) comes under "Stories" section. Thanks for the help.
Although it workout but still I believe there is a restriction to customization here from visual team services side. What do you think about that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. yes there are some restrictions. Those are mostly caused by the fact that there is an expectation on states and available fields in order to be treated as a "requirement".